# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec for unix find command with not path

Tags: java, linux, unix

tried multiple ways. Command to delete files under a set of directories except one specific subdirectory works fine when commmand run on Linux.

Same command when run via Java exec doesn't seem to recognize the path and everything gets wiped out.

```
find /test/filesdir/filexp -maxdepth 2 ! -path "/test/filesdir/filexp/node1/*" -type f -daystart -mtime +1 -delete
```

tried escpace character \ before the (") double quotes nothing seems to help.

any thoughts, please help.

java code used:

```
Process RunCmdLine = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CommandLine);
RunCmdLine.waitFor();
InputStream stdInput = RunCmdLine.getInputStream();
InputStream stdError = RunCmdLine.getErrorStream();
byte buffer[] = new byte [2048];
for (int read; (read = stdInput.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
System.out.write(buffer, 0, read);
inBuff.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
}
SystemErrMsg[0] = SystemErrMsg[0] + inBuff.toString();
```

i get the command line string from a database lookup where i have the 
entire find command

I added a sysout(commandline) right before the

```
Process RunCmdLine = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CommandLine);
```

and i see the command in the stdout file on the server. It looks good, when i run that command on the server it works fine.

Comment: Edit your question to include the java code you are using to launch this command.

Comment: I'd debug by `echo`-ing out fragments of the string and see how it actually ends up...

Comment: Also - but unrelated - sticking to Java coding conventions like using lowercase for variable names would make your code easier to read for others (and yourself in the long run)

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec(String)` claims another victim!

Never use this function. It has exactly zero valid use cases. Use the `Runtime.exec(String[])` version instead, or (even better) `ProcessBuilder`.

Both have two commonly used idioms. The first emulates C's simple and sloppy `system` by running the command in a shell:

```
// I don't care about security, my homework is due and I just want it to work ;_;
String CommandLine = "find /test/filesdir/filexp -maxdepth 2 " 
    + "! -path \"/test/filesdir/filexp/node1/*\" " 
    + "-type f -daystart -mtime +1 -delete";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", CommandLine });
```

and a secure and robust version closer to C's `execv(char*, char**)`:

```
// I have a strong understanding of UNIX and want a robust solution!
String[] commandArgs = new String[] {
    "find", "/test/filesdir/fileexp", "-maxdepth", "2",
      "!", "-path", "/test/filesdir/filexp/node1/*", "-type", "f",
      "-daystart", "-mtime", "+1", "-delete"
};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArgs);
```

The first just requires you to know how to use a shell. The second requires you to additionally know how a shell works behind the scenes, and can not be blindly copied based on this example.

Comment: the seccond option did not work as is as you had mentioned. Can you please help me understand what the issue is here? or point me to some reading material. Thanks.

Comment: @md1980 If you choose the second option, you take on full responsibility for [all the things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) a shell would normally do in exchange for more robust, secure and efficient execution. The posted answer works exactly like your dummy command, but if you e.g. tried to blindly replace `/test/filesdir/fileexp` with `/home/md1980/data-*`, then it will fail because [globbing is the shell's job](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06) and something you would have to do on your own.

Comment: `It has exactly zero valid use cases` why? If that was the case, why does it exist?

Comment: @Troyseph It seemed like a good idea in the 90s, when people had different ideas about correctness and reliability. Guessing at the user's intent and doing *something*, even if it's wrong, was considered a good thing similar to a human trying its best. Today we know that it's much more helpful if APIs either do the right thing or fail fast, and it should ideally never quietly return the wrong result.